# create query and filter option is gone?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, activities, filters

We used to have query and filter options under interactions / query activities and both options are gone.

Could you please clarify if there is a new way to create query or filters or this is due to permissions?

The only workaround I see it to create query of filter via automation but that does not make sense as there is no way to make changes to the folder structure of query or create new folders.

Please advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SFMC has been pushing to move people off of using interactions inside email studio, so during pretty much any maintenance or 'update' that they do (Like the one done Friday), they wipe away all those 'holes' they poke to allow certain people access to these inside Email studio and require you to go back and submit another help desk ticket to request this permission again. (I currently am doing the same)

It is very tiresome.  I agree with you it makes sense to have it in Email Studio, if for no other reason than that you can make edits to the emails/DEs used in the interactions without having to switch back and forth between Automation Studio and Email Studio app.